# Propostion 7.10.3 from Bogachev's "Real and functional analysis"

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

My question is about proof of proposition 7.10.3 (page 316) from Bogachev, Smolyanov "Real and functional analysis". I don't understand the end of this proof. Proposition 7.10.3 is below:

We have on an algebra $\mathcal{R}$ in a space $\Omega$ an additive set function $\Pi$ with values in the set of orthogonal projections in  a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose that for every $a, b \in H$ the complex function
$$
R\mapsto \Pi_{a,b}(R):=(\Pi(R)a,b)
$$
is countably additive on $\mathcal{R}$. Then the function $\Pi$ has a unique extenstion to a projection-valued measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$ generated by $\mathcal{R}$

In the proof we have proven that for every $S \in \sigma({\mathcal{R})}$ there exists a bounded self-adjoint operator $\Pi(S)$ with $(\Pi(S)a,b) = \Pi_{a,b}$ and that $0 \leq \Pi(S) \leq I$. Now we need to prove that $\Pi(S)$ is an orthogonal projection. Denote by $\mathcal{M}$ the class of sets $S \in \sigma(\mathcal{R})$ with this property. Obviosly $\mathcal{R}\subset \mathcal{M}$. It's also easy to check that $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class. Let $M_n \in \mathcal{M}$ be increasing to $M$ sequence of sets. In the book it is said that $\Pi(M_n)$ are projections to increasing closed subspaces $H_n$ and hence $M$ is projection onto the closure of the union of $H_n$.

I don't understand the last statement about increasing closed subspaces. All text in the proof before that place I understand. How to prove that this closed subspaces increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m, n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $m < n$.  Then $M_m \subseteq M_n$.  Let $P_1 = \Pi(M_m)$, $P_2 = \Pi(M_n)$ and $A=\Pi(M_n\setminus M_m)$.  We know that $P_1, P_2$ are orthogonal projections and $0\le A \le 1$.

In case you haven't done this we show that $P_1 + A = P_2$.  For each $a, b\in H$, $\Pi_{a,b}\rvert_{\mathcal{R}}$ is $\sigma$-additive on $\mathcal{R}$, and $\Pi_{a,b}$ is its $\sigma$-additive extension to $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$.  This implies that for all $a, b\in H$
$$
\begin{align}
\Pi_{a,b}(M_m) + \Pi_{a,b}(M_n\setminus M_m) &= \Pi_{a,b}(M_n)\\
\langle \Pi(M_m)a,b\rangle + \langle \Pi(M_n\setminus M_m)a,b\rangle &= \langle \Pi(M_n)a,b\rangle\\
\langle P_1 a,b\rangle + \langle A a,b\rangle &= \langle P_2 a,b\rangle\end{align}
$$
and this implies that $P_1 + A = P_2$ as operators.

Now let $x\in \operatorname{Range}(P_1)$ with $\|x\| = 1$.  Then $P_1 x = x$ and
$$\langle P_1 x, x\rangle + \langle Ax, x\rangle = \langle P_2x, x\rangle$$
But $\langle P_1 x, x\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle = 1$ and $\langle Ax, x\rangle \ge 0$ (since $A\ge 0$.)  So $\langle P_2x, x\rangle \ge 1$.  But $0\le P_2\le 1$, so $\langle P_2 x, x\rangle = 1$.

Now, if $P$ is any orthogonal projection whatsoever, $\langle Px, x \rangle = \langle P^2x, x \rangle = \langle P^* Px, x \rangle = \|Px\|^2$.  So from $\langle P_2 x, x\rangle = 1$ follows $\|P_2 x\| = 1$ and this implies that $x\in \operatorname{Range}(P_2)$, since an orthogonal projection actually reduces the norm of any non-zero vector not in its range.

This completes the proof that $\operatorname{Range}(P_1) \subseteq \operatorname{Range}(P_2)$, and it's the only part you indicated you don't understand.